# Java main method not found error on Windows 10 even with correct main signature

Tags: java

I have a couple of Java files A.java and B.java that use a common jar file C.jar.  B.java contains reference variables to the object of type A.  B.java contains the main method

I compiled using the following command.

```
javac -cp C.jar A.java B.java
```

It compiles.

However, when I run it says main method not found.

I ran

```
java -cp C.jar B
```

Am I making some mistake in my commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I making some mistake in my commands?

Yes - you're not including *anything* apart from `C.jar` when trying to run.

Use

```
java -cp C.jar;. // Windows
java -cp C.jar:. // Unix
```

So that you're including the current directory (which is where `A.class` and `B.class` are, presumably) on the classpath.